# Link id's between two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables:

1. one for blog posts
2. one for blog post images

The second one stores only image names.

How can I link a blog post id to an image id?

Comment: Use a join, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use inner join to join your 2 tables

```
SELECT table1.something, table2.something
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.ID=table2.ID;
```

you can use the code above to join your tables.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add the post id in your photo id table. By using where clause in  select query yo can link two table. Use join query to link those two tables.